# How to create an HTMLElement from a string?

Tags: c#, string

I have a `string` containing HTML. I want to generate an `HtmlElement` from it, so I could append it to another element using the `AppendChild` method.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
new HtmlElement(myString);
```

But I get the following error:

> 'HtmlElement' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

and no IntelliSense to indicate how many arguments the `HtmlElement`'s constructor actually takes. In fact, it seems to be un-instantiable altogether, but `HtmlElement` is not static nor abstract so I do not see any reason for it to be the case.

So is it even possible to create an `HtmlElement` from a string, and if so - how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd call

```
var newElement = document.CreateElement("span");
```

where `document` is an instance of `HtmlDocument`.
and then assign the actual content like so:

```
newElement.OuterHtml = "<span>content</span>";
```

The constructor of `HtmlElement` is [internal](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/HtmlElement.cs,52), so you need a document to create an instance from.

Documents also cannot be created out of thin air, a webbrowser control is needed to host everything.

Comment: Thanks! What if I do not have the knowledge of the type of the element I want to create, except from within the HTML itself? Do I need to manually extract this information from the HTML?

Comment: yes - you can walk the document object model and then [modify it as you see fit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I would be grateful if you could add an example in your answer. Thank you.